# Laws of large numbers and independence

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

I just did a brief review of various sources, and they all specify that if $X_i$'s are independent, identically distributed random variables, then $S_n/n \rightarrow E(X_i)$ (with respect to various notions of convergence).  Do the various $X_i$'s really need to be independent?

Comment: Hint: finite Markov chains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To construct some cases where they are dependent and still the convergence still holds is possible, so I suppose you are looking for a case of dependence when it does not hold.

What about setting $X_0=N(0,1)$. Now, for all $i$, repeatedly sample from $N(0,1)$ for some variable $Y_i$ until $sgn(Y_i)=sgn(X_{i-1})$ and set $X_i=Y_i$. Then consider the sum of the $X_i$'s.

Edit 1:

Even simpler. Set $X_0=-1$ with probability $1/2$, and $X_0=+1$ with probability $1/2$. Now set $X_i=X_{i-1}$. Then $S_n/n\rightarrow \pm 1$ and $E[X_i]=0$.

Note that the theorem is for $S_n/n$ and not $E[S_n]/n$.

Edit 2, in response to Did's comment:

Let $X_0=-1$ with probability $1/2$, and $X_0=+1$ with probability $1/2$ and set $X_i=-X_{i-1}$, now $S_n/n \rightarrow0=E[X_i]$

In conclusion, when you have dependent RVs, it is possible to have cases where the LLN holds, but to have other cases where the LLN does not hold.

Comment: Rather than repeated sampling, for $i > 0$ you could draw $Y_i$ from $N(0,1)$ and then set $X_i = \operatorname{sgn}(X_0)\cdot |Y_i|$.  I think this has the same joint distribution.

Comment: Could the downvoter please elaborate their reason(s) for downvoting?

Comment: In these two examples, $S_n/n$ does not converge to $E(X_0)$.

Comment: That's the point. The dependence can be constructed in a way that it does not converge. The original question asked "Do the various Xi's really need to be independent?". To which the answer is 'not necessarily', which I said in the first paragraph, and then gave examples of how dependence can ruin the convergence.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was unclear.  I meant "is independence a necessary hypothesis to prove convergence".  Bhoot did get the meaning.  Also, that last example was great.  Thanks.

Comment: Just to be sure: independence is not a necessary condition, it is only a sufficient condition. There are cases with dependent $X_i$ which both satisfy the convergence, and do not satisfy the convergence. But I get your gist.

Answer (score 4):

The Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem can be considered to be a generalization of the Strong Law of Large Numbers to identically distributed but dependent sequences.

Comment: Yup.  Bit of an uphill battle for someone new to the literature to dive into ergodicity......

Answer (score 2):

No.  For instance, if you have a *stationary* time series with *autocovariances* $\gamma_j$ satisfying $0<\sum_j \gamma_j^2<\infty$ then one has convergence, also, since

$$V\Bigl( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^n X_t \Bigr)=
\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{t=1}^n \sum_{s=1}^n \gamma_{t-s} \to 0,$$

as $n\to\infty.$